# Syntax highlighting in Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting

I am developing an Eclipse plugin to act as an IDE for the Soar language, but am having trouble figuring out how to get the syntax highlighting to work for more nontrivial cases. Specifically, I need to be able to match the same line of text to two different text rules, but it appears that you can only match one at a time. Here's an example:

```
set myVar "<ab$cde-f>"
```

The part that needs special highlighting is the part inside the quotation marks. I need `"<ab` to be highlighted one color, `$cde` to be highlighted another, and -`f>"` to be highlighted the same as `"<ab`. My idea was to create a few different rules, one that matches `"<ab` and one that matches anything after the `$cde` character, but this second part has proven to be quite difficult, because the `$cde` part can terminate in many different ways, not just with a `-` character.In addition, I cannot only highlight this sections everywhere in the code, only in this particular use case. Can anyone help me figure out how to write a rule to match this?

Sorry if this is confusing or disorganized in any way, it's quite a specific problem.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at [Eclipse XText](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/) rather than trying to do this yourself.

Comment: What do you mean rule? What rules are you already using? What are you using that requires "rules"?

Comment: Assuming these are the JFace rules you are talking about you probably want to use a partition scanner so you can handle the quoted text with a different set of rules.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, I'm a bit new to the codebase and Eclipse in general.

Comment: Yes, they are jface rules. The way it works now is that we have a bunch of classes that extend Multiline rule or IRule, and those are all applied in a RuleBasedScanner class. Specifically, we have one called regexRule that can match lines based on regexes, which is how I made the other rules.

Comment: @greg-449, that looks like a good solution, but unfortunately we have quite a bit of legacy code that mostly works so we can't really change methods at this time. 

Could you explain more about how the partition scanner works, and how it's different from the RuleBasedScanner we have now?

Comment: A Partition Scanner is a different thing. It divides the document in to multiple partitions. You then define a different set of rules for each partition. Look at `IDocument.setDocumentPartitioner`

Comment: Would that allow me to split up lines into smaller lines? All the examples I found online only split up lines in the file, but not the lines itself.